# Jersey Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, jersey

I am a beginner in Jersey library.. I am stuck on the following statement:

```
Client c = Client.create();
WebResource web = c.resource(url);
ClientResponse resp = web.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class) // Why are we using reflection here?
```

Also Reflection is also used in :

```
resp.getEntity(String.class); // Why are we passing class<String> to getEntity()?
```

I want to know why are we passing these parameters to the above methods?

Comment: What is the exact question? It isn't really reflection what you see. Its a way to provide 'typeSafety' with 'generic types' without extra class casting. Is it not working?

Comment: It is working but I am not able to figure out the use of passing these parameters

Comment: You're telling jersey what java type you want the raw request body converted to.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is a method to provide type safty with generic types. I suspect there is still reflection going on in the background (for object instance construction), but its not what you are doing yourself.

Consider the following method:

```
public <T> T get(Class<T> type) { \* content *\}
```

The above is what the declaration would look like. Besides the reflection in the background (most likely needed for object-instance construction) this allows you to get the 'correct' type without casting. Otherwise you would need to do something like:

```
MyType object = (MyType) resp.getEntity();
```

I'm not sure if this answers the question? (Otherwise let us know)